# Why no return value from function named 'link_to' with PHPUnit in Laravel?

Tags: tdd, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4, bdd

Currently following a Laravel 4 book on writing tests, the following returns no output from PHPUnit if the function is named `link_to()`, but does return the result if it is named something else like `link_tox()`. Why is this?

**app/helpers.php**

```
<?php

function link_to($url, $body) {
    $url = url($url);
    return "<a href='{$url}'>{$body}</a>";
}
```

**app/tests/ExampleTests.php**

```
<?php


class FunctionsTest extends TestCase {

    public function testGeneratesAnchorTag() {
        $actual = link_to('dogs/1', 'Show Dog');
        $expected = "<a href='http://localhost/dogs/1'>Show Dog</a>";

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

}
```

Comment: there might already be a function called link_to() - maybe make your helper function a class called MyHelpers::link_to() ?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Why are there no errors shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel already has a [link_to function](http://laravel.com/api/function-link_to.html).